# Sum of Article Numbers with Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

This is an example table of how the data is structured

| Article | Amount | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120132030 | 20 | Group1 |
| 190182034 | 10 | Group2 |
| 120132030 | 10 | Group1 |
| 120132030 | 5 | Group2 |

I am looking for a way to summarise the quantity of several article numbers. However, only the article numbers with the same group should be summarised. It would be best if it were possible with Power Query...

I have already tried to add up the individual article numbers using the group function. But unfortunately I didn't get any further with the conditions of the groups.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 2):

In PowerQuery, click-select the Article and Group columns, right click, Group by... and choose to sum the amount field

[image]

Alternatively, to just count instances, click-select the Article and Group columns, right click, Group by... and use default to count rows

[image]

output from above would be one of these two, where the Articles are summarized within each group

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd> function if applicable, but note it is available for users those who are in `Beta Channel`

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(CHOOSECOLS(A2:C5,3,1),INDEX(A2:C5,,2),SUM,,0)
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=PIVOTBY(CHOOSECOLS(A2:C5,3,1),,INDEX(A2:C5,,2),SUM,,0)
```

---

Or, With <kbd>MMULT()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(C2:C5,A2:A5,MMULT(N(C2:C5&"|"&A2:A5=TOROW(C2:C5&"|"&A2:A5)),B2:B5)))
```

---

And why not have all the aggregations using one function to spill, using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=PIVOTBY(CHOOSECOLS(A2:C5,3,1),,INDEX(A2:C5,,2),HSTACK(SUM,COUNT,AVERAGE))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(HSTACK(C2:C5,A2:A5),B2:B5,HSTACK(SUM,COUNT,AVERAGE,MIN,MAX,MEDIAN))
```

---